# Selecting rows from dataframe by consecutive numerical values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns like this

```
category               label    
POLITICS                 0  
WELLNESS                 1  
ENTERTAINMENT            2  
STYLE & BEAUTY           3  
TRAVEL                   4  
PARENTING                5  
FOOD & DRINK             6  
...
```

I want to select the rows containing labels, say 0 to 3.

I can do it like this  but it is very manual.  I may have some 20 rows to select.

```
df.loc[(df.label == 0)|(df.label == 1)|(df.label == 2)|(df.label == 3)....
```

is there a better way?

Comment: `df.loc[df['label'].between(0, 3)]` or `df.loc[df['label'].isin([0, 1, 2, 3])]`